# including an external file in postfix aliases file using ":include:" directive

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

Some entries in my postfix alias file are static, whereas others are intended to be dynamic, and updated via a cron-job script every hour.  I would like to have the static entries be in a file by themselves, and simply include the dynamic entries via an ":include:" directive to another file.  That way, my script can modify the dynamic entries without ever touching the static entries file.

Is this possible?

( P.S.  I know the :include: directive can be used as the right-hand-side of an alias, I just want to know if it can also be used to include new aliases entirely )

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple [`alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) (or [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps)).

Example:

> alias_maps = hash:/etc/mail/aliases hash:/etc/mail/aliases-crongend

Though if you really want dynamic aliases you might try a different table type, such as [`mysql`](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html) and skip the cronscript all together.